# Which one is correct “Where are” or “Where is”?

Tags: subject-verb-agreement, compound-subjects

I am confused which one is right.

> Where is personname1 and personname2 ?

or.

> Where are personname1 and personname2 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you answered the question you would say:

> A and B are here.

and **not**:

> A and B is here.

Therefore, to turn it into a question, you just put "where" at the beginning and the verb:

> Where are person1 and person2?

Comment: Note that in some cases ["where is" is more natural than "where are"](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/13333/143595) despite the fact that "where is" is grammatically incorrect for the case.